# DataTables - How to clear out excess column headers from a previously loaded DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am about to wrap up with my Census Database table web app, and just have one more question.  I have been trying to figure out how do I clear excess column headers when loading a smaller DataTable after a larger one.  For example, I have the following functions:

```
function nationalAgeGender() {
    (function($) {
        $('#data-entry').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bScrollInfinite": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true ,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bDestroy": true,   
            "iDisplayLength": -1,   
            "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
            "aaSorting": [[8,'asc']],
            "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/NationalAgeGender.php",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sTitle": "Age group" },
                { "sTitle": "Total population (both genders)" },
                { "sTitle": "Male population" },
                { "sTitle": "Female population" },
                { "sTitle": "% (both genders)" },
                { "sTitle": "Male %" },
                { "sTitle": "Female %" },
                { "sTitle": "Males per 100 females" },
                { "bVisible": false }
            ]
        });
    })(jQuery);
}

function combinedAgeGender() {
    (function($) {
        $('#data-entry').dataTable({
           "bProcessing": true,
           "bScrollInfinite": true,
           "bScrollCollapse": true ,
           "bAutoWidth": false, 
           "iDisplayLength": -1,
           "bDestroy": true,
           "sDom": '<"top">rt<"bottom">',
           "aaSorting": [[8,'asc']],
           "sAjaxSource": "/CensusDatabase/database_scripts/CombinedAgeGender.php",
           "aoColumns": [
               { "sTitle": "Age group" },
               { "sTitle": "National total population (both genders)" },
               { "sTitle": "National male population" },
               { "sTitle": "National female population" },
               { "sTitle": "National % (both genders)" },
               { "sTitle": "National male %" },
               { "sTitle": "National female %" },
               { "sTitle": "National males per 100 females" },
               { "bVisible": false }, 
               { "bVisible": false }, 
               { "sTitle": "Arizona total population (both genders)" },
               { "sTitle": "Arizona male population" },
               { "sTitle": "Arizona female population" },
               { "sTitle": "Arizona % (both genders)" },
               { "sTitle": "Arizona male %" },
               { "sTitle": "Arizona female %" },
               { "sTitle": "Arizona males per 100 females" }

           ]
       });
   })(jQuery);
}
```

If I load the second function first and then load the first one, I get the following result:
[image: Excess columns]

I tried adding this code to my first function:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
    $('#data-entry thead').html('');            
}
```

However, it clears out ALL of the columns instead of just the excess ones.

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Maybe have two different elements for each function instead of a single #data-entry and hide/show each other, or delete/recreate the element as the first line of each function.

Comment: Okay, I tried using different elements, however, I want to only show one table at a time, and now multiple tables show up when opening two different types of tables.

Comment: Oh wait, I needed to add the `hide()` function to the other tables each time I call my functions.

Comment: Yeh, in the beginning of each function you would hide the other, show the current.